# Function trim in js with regexp

Tags: php, javascript, regex, trim

I want to remove beginning and ending spaces from a string, like the function `trim()` in PHP. I want to do this with a regexp. In PHP I'd do this:

```
$str = "    a s d  ";
$mytrim = preg_match_all("#^\s*([^\s].*)\s*$#U", $str, $mas);
echo $mas[1][0];
```

I don't know how to do this because in Javscript regex, this is not true: "all except asked symbols - `[^some symbols]`". I can do this with two regexes but I'm interested how I can do it with one?

Comment: Steve Leventhal (a JS regex guru) has a nice write up. See: [Faster JavaScript Trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript) (p.s. Please do a search next time - this question gets asked a lot!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first google result of "javascript trim":

```
var text = '   hello   ';
text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy `var newText = "text".replace(/#^\s*([^\s].*)\s*$#U/g, '');`

in newText the data that was matched by your regex is replaced with ''

ore you could just use trim from phpjs http://phpjs.org/functions/trim:566